# Blade Template Section Error

Tags: laravel

I am getting a syntax error using blade templating...

```
<title>
    @section('title')
        this is my title
    @show
</title>
```

The generated output fails to close the opening PHP tag?

```
<title>
    <?php $__env->startSection('title')
        this is my title
    <?php echo $__env->yieldSection(); ?>
</title>
```

If i do the following it works as expected...

```
<title>
    @section('title'); ?>
        this is my title
    @show
</title>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? There is nothing wrong with it. I believe you actually have them on a single line, which will cause this issue.

Comment: @Robbo definitely not on a single line. I have tried stripping everything out of the <head> tag expect for my <title> but still no change... got me buggered :(

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe your line endings are messing with the regex the compiler uses?

Comment: @Robbo spot on mate... turns out my lines were ending in CR. I find it interesting that this happened?

Comment: Just to do with the compilers regex so it knows where things start and end. Same reason that you can get similar errors with blade syntax on the same line. I do hope to oneday make a blade compiler that doesn't have issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code as follows,

```
<title>
    @section('title')
        this is my title
    @stop
</title>
```

***Notice:*** I have changed **@show** to **@stop** inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an EOL conversion problem.
If you are using Notepad++ on Windows be sure that you have `'Edit/EOL Conversion/Windows Format'`.